# Make a line with 2 different colors , one in the center and another at the edges

Tags: css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8uFt.png)

I have this kind of a line, I want to make something like this but can't find how to do it . Should I use 2 lines one on another for achieve this effect or can I make it in another way ? I was also looking on `linear-gradient` , but didn't get the same result . Or it have to be something like different opacity at the edges ?

Comment: if it event gradient how can I achieve this effect ?what is the answer here ?

Comment: please use the radial gradient with the fill opacity on it i mean use the rgba colors for the corners in radial gradient.

Answer (score 2):

codepen link https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/KbwxRp

```css
body {
  background:#262626;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.line {
  width:1px;
  height:400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626, #a0a0a0, #262626);
  filter:blur(.8px);
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve it by giving a CSS background image with `linear-gradient` background to an empty div object.

the code will probably look something like this snippet:

```css
.two_colored_line {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, red);
}
```

```html
<div class='two_colored_line'></div>
```

you can find more information here: [CSS Linear Gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Comment: concise code @sina-mansour-l, well done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option for you... It's a simple line gradient.

```css
#line-parent {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#line {
  height: 98vh;
  width: 3px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, grey, black);
}
```

```html
<div id="line-parent">
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do this with gradient.

```css
.line{height:200px; width:2px; margin:auto; background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#0000001c,#000,#0000001a);}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```